# Evaluate the line integral $\int_C xy^4 ds $ of a half circle

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, parametrization

> Evaluate the line integral where $C$ is the given curve:
>   $\int_C xy^4 ds $, $C$ it the right half of the circle $x^2+y^2=16$

[image]

I was following a similar example in my book and parameterized $t$ by making $x = \cos t$ and $y = \sin t$ and using the line integral equation, but I got a small fraction while the answer is a large number. I looked at the example twice and checked my problem twice, so I'm not sure what I'm missing. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: the correct parameterization is x=4*cos(t), y=4*sin(t)

Comment: I actually was looking at my problem again and just realized that lol

Comment: alright I plugged in the right parametric values and my radical came out to be 1/4 and the whole thing came out to be 512/5 which is 102.4.. but the right answer is way bigger...???

Comment: you have to put also a $\rho$ to take into account the variables change

Comment: If you want someone to point out where you’re going wrong, you should include your work in the question instead of simply writing that you keep getting the wrong answer.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). To help you get started,  retyped some formulas from your picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$r(t)=(4\cos t,\,4\sin t)\;,\;\;-\frac\pi2\le t\le\frac\pi2\implies \text{our integral is}$$

$$\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}4\cos t(4\sin t)^4\left\|r'(t)\right\|dt=1,024\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\cos t\,\sin^4t\cdot4\,dt=\left.\frac{4,096}5\sin^5t\right|_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}=\frac{8,192}5$$

Comment: how did you get the 4 for the norm of r'(t) ?

Comment: why do you use commata?

Comment: wait nevermind i see it.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include the radius. The substitution $x= \cos t$, $y= \sin t$ parametrizes a circle of radius $1$.
But $C$ is a subset of a circle of radius $4$.

Answer (score 0):

The correct parameterization is $x=4\cos(t), y=4\sin(t)$.